# How can I create a record with an ID from a variable?

Tags: database, surrealdb

I'm trying to create a record in SurrealQL with a variable:

```
CREATE student:$name SET age = 38
```

but for some reason the syntax isn't allowed. Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE type::thing("student", $name) SET age 38
```

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/functions/type#thing covers this, but you can use a type function to create a record link, which in your case can be passed to CREATE.